Database storing method / sql
I have form where user-A choose minimum of 1 and maximum of 3 from 99 checkboxes.
Each checkbox has value from 1 to 99. (to be clear: first checkbox.value = 1.... last.checkbox.value = 99).
And currently I have three columns in my db (column1, column2, column3), each for one selected checkbox value.
(prob. not matter for this question but: If under three checkboxes is provided, the related column will be null).
NOW user-B selects his own single value from 1 to 99, and this value will be stored in column "singlevalue".
NEXT user-B does an query:
SELECT * 
FROM user-A-table 
WHERE '$singlevalue' = $column1
   OR '$singlevalue' = $column2
   OR '$singlevalue' = $column3;

So currently that query can be done with an OR clause (or using IN, which I guess is the same as using OR).
Problem is that I want to avoid using OR, so instead I need a way to store the upto three values from the three selected checkboxes into one column, so the query would be more sufficient:
SELECT * 
FROM user-A-table 
WHERE '$singlevalue' = $column123; <-- and then index this column

Obviously storing the three values as a comma-separated string is not way to go here.
And I don't know could there even be some simple trick for this. The solution will surely need backend processing which is ok, because the goal is to make the query work so I can just put an index to the $column123, which would contain all the possible combinations of the up to three selected values from 1 to 99.
I have read about bitwise and bitmasking solutions for this, but they seem complicated and may produce too big values for my case, especially if user-A selects values: 97, 98 and 99.

Better idea: go normalized.

I did not ask this.

Well you should have, because that's the real answer. Your design is completely broken. UserA should not have their own table, there should be a single table with a User column. The "checkbox" values should go into rows, not columns, eg (User, CheckboxName, Value) and you may need another table for this.

what if I have two users in my whole project. And other one has a table. and I cannot go normalized schema. Then, whats the solution(s) for my question... I am asking solutions for my exact example case.

If you don't want a table storing up to three rows per user for the checkboxes, then your three columns and OR is already the best solution. You can add three separate indexes, one for each column. If OR gets too slow, you may try to have three queries combined with UNION ALL instead.
